# Personality replacement clinic. Clinic worker plans to re-upload their old lover

Tags: story-identification, mind-uploading

Personality replacement has become an acceptable alternative to suicide.  If you cannot go on as yourself, become someone new.  You keep your old memories but they feel more like someone else's biography.

The protagonist has done this, and eventually learns that her new personality is recorded from a woman who died.  The dead woman's lover works in the clinic, and gimmicked the system so that the next client with body type similar enough to hers should get her stored personality.

This feels like a novelette from before 1980.  (I don't think it is the same story as in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43188/short-story-about-a-girl-who-lost-replaced-her-personality).)

Answer (score 9):

I think this is "[Trojan Horse](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40846)" by Michael Swanwick.

The story is set in a lunar base, in a world where workers download new personalities - "wetware" - for their jobs. They wear specific face paint to indicate that they are in worker mode.

The protagonist, Elin, lost her own personality in an accident, and is given a new one by a clinic - as you remember, it turns out that the clinic worker, Tory, has given her the personality of his former lover, Coral.

However she is not dead, but

> elevated to godhood

during an experiment. Elin decides to participate in a repeat of the experiment.

I read it in Terry Carr's Best Science Fiction of the Year 1985, but you can read it online at Baen's site [here](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/1596061781/1596061781___4.htm).

Comment: Swanwick expanded on some of the same concepts (in the same setting?) a couple years later in the novel *Vacuum Flowers*, in which the protagonist also receives the personality of someone who has died—although for different reasons and with very different consequences.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I have a collection of Swanwick shorts somewhere; will look for it.